# Capturing "inner slices" of a character vector in R

Tags: r

I have a character vector, like so:

```
test <- c(1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37)
```

I want to return the numbers in the middle, like so:

```
"2:6"   "8:12"  "14:18" "20:24" "26:30" "32:36"
```

I succeeded in doing it, but it's not as robust as I would like it to be:

```
rangefunc <- function(x){
  paste(x+1, x+5, sep = ":")
}
head(sapply(test, rangefunc))
```

Clearly, this is a workable solution, but it's not future-proof for cases where the separation between the numbers isn't uniform throughout (e.g., always 6) or where the separation is just different (i.e., not 6).  To handle such potential cases in my character vector `test`, how do I construct a more robust function than:

```
rangefunc <- function(x){
  paste(x+1, x+5, sep = ":")
}
```

Comment: See answer below, but it's not completely general, is it possible that two consecutive numbers are the same or only different by 1 or 2 units, if so what to do with these 3 cases ?

Comment: No, two consecutive numbers will never be the same.  Not sure about the other edge cases -- maybe.

Comment: What would you expect with a vector like this: test <- c(1, 7, 37, 38)?

Comment: @DJV Ah yes, in that case I don't have any separations with 1 or 2 units.  Thanks for boiling this down to an example.

Comment: `c(1, 7, 37, 39)` is also problematic, i don't know if you want '38:38' or just '38'

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Nope, in my case, I wouldn't have to deal with situations like that.

Comment: alright, then I have nothing to add to my solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
sapply(seq_along(test[-1]),function(i) paste0(test[i]+1,":",test[i+1]-1))
# [1] "2:6"   "8:12"  "14:18" "20:24" "26:30" "32:36"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
paste(head(test, -1) + 1, tail(test, -1) - 1, sep = ':')
# [1] "2:6"   "8:12"  "14:18" "20:24" "26:30" "32:36"
```

It seems like this output might not be very useful though (depending on why you want it). You may want something like this instead

```
data.frame(start = head(test, -1) + 1
           , end = tail(test, -1) - 1)

#   start end
# 1     2   6
# 2     8  12
# 3    14  18
# 4    20  24
# 5    26  30
# 6    32  36
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `zoo::rollapply` as:

```
test <- c(1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31, 37)

library(zoo)

rollapply(test, 2, function(x)paste(x[1]+1,x[2]-1, sep=":"))
#[1] "2:6"   "8:12"  "14:18" "20:24" "26:30" "32:36
```